# Assigning base part only from one object to another

Tags: c++

I have simple inheritance when class B derives from A. A contains some members definition of simple types, no pointers. The B class is more complex and may contain pointers for some logic connections between objects. If I have two objects of type B (e.g. b1 and b2), how to write correctly the assignment when I am copying only A-part of b2 to b1.
The construction which works for me is: `*(A*)&b1 = *(A*)&b2`. But what is the correct way to implement this on the modern C++?

Comment: I would use a separate function (even implemented as *this = rhs ;)

Comment: `(A&)b1 = b2;` does the same thing and avoids cruft

Answer (score 0):

a) What you're doing looks technically correct (i.e. IMHO it should work everywhere)

b) However, as any code with casts, it is cumbersome and error-prone

c) To make it more readable, I'd suggest to add something like this:

```
class A {
  //...
  public:
  void copyA(const A& other) {
    *this = *other;
  }
};
```

to your class A, then you'll be able to call much more obvious b1.copyA(b2) instead of your current (correct, but error-prone) code.